# Class.isAssignableFrom gives wrong results in certain situation

Tags: java, class, reflection, classloader

I'm really confused about the behaviour. In a JBoss 7, I am retrieving all Classes with @Entity Annotation and then I need to find all of them that implement the interface "BusinessObject".

This is the method to do it:

```
     private Set<Class<? extends BusinessObject>> findEntityClasses() {
        //  Alle Klassen holen, die mit "@Entity" annotiert sind. Dabei werden Hibernate- wie auch javax.persistence Annotations genommen
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("de.something.b4");
        Set<Class<?>> entityClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);

        //Jetzt in das finale Set nur die Klassen kopieren, die von  BusinessObject erben. Weil andere benutzen wir hier nicht!
        Set<Class<? extends BusinessObject>> boClasses = new HashSet<Class<? extends BusinessObject>>();
        try {
          List<Class> l = new ArrayList<Class>(entityClasses);

          for (Class currentClass : l) {
            //Class newCurrentClass = Class.forName(currentClass.getName());
            if (BusinessObject.class.isAssignableFrom(currentClass)) {
              boClasses.add(currentClass);
            }

          }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
          System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }

        return boClasses;
      }
```

Please notice the commented-out line with Class.forName()!

With this commented-out, isAssignableFrom **always** returns true even if currentClass does not implement BusinessObject.

As soon as I remove the comment on Class.forName() and once it's called something happens to this class so that all subsequent calls to isAssignableFrom return the correct value as expected.

I'm sure this has some reason and Class.forName() does something to the class or the classloader but I couldn't figure out what. Does anybody have an idea about this behaviour?

Comment: Try using Class.forName( currentClass.getName(), false, this.getClass().getClassloader() ), see if that still causes problems.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. When using `Class.forName`, keep in mind that it also fully initializes a class. So, @Smith_61's comment could lead into the right direction.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose that was my thinking. Reflections is returning in uninitialized Class object, and a JVM bug is failing to initialize the class when used in this context. What JVM/OS are you using? I can't replicate on JVM 8, Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and sorry - the previously posted code didn't work even _with_ Class.forName() - I stripped it a little bit to prettify but something might have been lost. I edited the original post with my actual code. With this I can reproduce the behaviour. I already tried with initialize false, but even with false - after calling Class.forName() everything works as expected. Also - if it's interesting - the class BusinessObject classes and this code reside in different jars deployed in an ear.

Comment: @philli What is your OS/JVM information?

Comment: @Smith_61 it's JBoss 7.1.3 on some Redhat Linux Machine and Java 1.6.0_45, 64bit

Comment: @philli This is going to sound unhelpful, but it is 3 in the morning. IMO, I think it is a JVM bug. Since I don't have a similar machine to test on and I can not replicate it on my machine, I can not test my theory. Since there is a known workaround for it, by placing the `Class.forName` before calling it. I would suggest leaving that before with a comment as to why it is there, and maybe create an issue with jboss.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) of `Class.forName()`:

> A call to `forName("X")` causes the class named `X` to be initialized.

So if you uncomment `Class.forName(currentClass.getName());` it will initialize the class and therefore `Class.isAssignableFrom()` will be able to properly test if `BusinessObject` is implemented by the class (`Reflections` might not initialize them).

Comment: He is still using the same Class object though, not the one returned from Class.forName()

Comment: @Smith_61 Yeah, you're right, then probably it's just the other quoted javadoc part: "causes the class named `X` to be initialized".

Comment: That was my thinking, but I'm failing to replicate it on all my installed JVMs.